# ASUS USB-AC68 not connecting in Linux Mint

Tags: kernel, drivers, compiling, kernel-modules, asus

I recently bought a [ASUS USB-AC68](https://www.asus.com/us/Networking/USB-AC68/specifications/) which uses the [Realtek RTL8814AU chipset](https://wikidevi.com/wiki/ASUS_USB-AC68), to replace the outdated WiFi card of my (new) PC, but there are no downloadable Linux drivers from the OEM. At the directive of my father and a tutorial (see source 1), it failed so I tried another site (see source 2), but same result.

I couldn't make any of these work on my Linux, for some compilation reasons I don't understand nor can fix.

PC dual-boot:

```
    ASUS VIVOBOOK 17

    Linux MINT

    Window
```

The wifi adapter: https://wikidevi.com/wiki/ASUS_USB-AC68

Source: https://ubuntu-mate.community/t/a-dual-band-usb-wi-fi-adapter-that-works-and-how-to-find-them/15173.

Asus USB-AC68 [0b05:1817] [drivers][3](https://www.asus.com/us/Networking/USB-AC68/HelpDesk_Download/)?

Driver:

https://github.com/nazar-pc/RTL8814AU.git

https://github.com/diederikdehaas/rtl8814AU

Compilation:

DRIVER 1:

```
clement-monfort@clementmonfort-VivoBook-17-ASUS-Laptop-X705UBR:~/Bureau/RTL8814AU$ sudo ./dkms-install.sh 
[sudo] password for clement-monfort:         
About to run dkms install steps...
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/usr/src/rtl8814au-4.3.21’: File exists
Error! DKMS tree already contains: rtl8814au-4.3.21
You cannot add the same module/version combo more than once.

Kernel preparation unnecessary for this kernel.  Skipping...

Building module:
cleaning build area...
'make'...(bad exit status: 2)
ERROR (dkms apport): binary package for rtl8814au: 4.3.21 not found
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 4.15.0-45-generic (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/rtl8814au/4.3.21/build/make.log for more information.

Kernel preparation unnecessary for this kernel.  Skipping...

Building module:
cleaning build area...
'make'...(bad exit status: 2)
ERROR (dkms apport): binary package for rtl8814au: 4.3.21 not found
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 4.15.0-45-generic (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/rtl8814au/4.3.21/build/make.log for more information.
Finished running dkms install steps.
clement-monfort@clementmonfort-VivoBook-17-ASUS-Laptop-X705UBR:~/Bureau/RTL8814AU$ sudo modprobe rtl8814au
modprobe: FATAL: Module rtl8814au not found in directory /lib/modules/4.15.0-45-generic
```

DRIVER 2:

```
clement-monfort@clementmonfort-VivoBook-17-ASUS-Laptop-X705UBR:~/Bureau/rtl8814au$ sudo make && sudo make install
[sudo] password for clement-monfort:         
make ARCH=x86_64 CROSS_COMPILE= -C /lib/modules/4.15.0-45-generic/build M=/home/clement-monfort/Bureau/rtl8814au  modules
make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.15.0-45-generic'
  CC [M]  /home/clement-monfort/Bureau/rtl8814au/core/rtw_cmd.o
gcc: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-fstack-protector-strong’
scripts/Makefile.build:332: recipe for target '/home/clement-monfort/Bureau/rtl8814au/core/rtw_cmd.o' failed
make[2]: *** [/home/clement-monfort/Bureau/rtl8814au/core/rtw_cmd.o] Error 1
Makefile:1551: recipe for target '_module_/home/clement-monfort/Bureau/rtl8814au' failed
make[1]: *** [_module_/home/clement-monfort/Bureau/rtl8814au] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.15.0-45-generic'
Makefile:1699: recipe for target 'modules' failed
make: *** [modules] Error 2
clement-monfort@clementmonfort-VivoBook-17-ASUS-Laptop-X705UBR:~/Bureau/rtl8814au$ sudo modprobe -v 8814au
modprobe: FATAL: Module 8814au not found in directory /lib/modules/4.15.0-45-generic
```